# Hide other windows (CMD + Option + H) shortcut for VS Code on macOS

Tags: visual-studio-code

In proper mac applications you can use command+option+H to hide all apps except the currently active program. This does not work in VS Code for some reason. Is there a way to get this functionality?

Comment: I don't know how to fix it, but at present there is an open issue that may be relevant: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/98246

Answer (score 0):

You could try [this](https://superuser.com/a/1328252) I found setting each app individually worked for me.

*Senario*

I wanted to prevent `vscode` from using `Hide Visual Studio Code` which, by default was mapped onto `cmd+H` keyboard shortcut. I changed it to the way illustrated in the screegrab and it worked. Perhaps you could do the same?

*Edit*

I actually attemped it and it worked with the same combo you wanted. See the screen grab below:

[image]
[image]

Happy coding =)